# How to write a method that adds `self` as a mutable trait reference to a collection?

Tags: rust

I have a trait `Foo` and a struct `Bar`. `Bar` has a `Vec` field which holds any reference that implements `Foo`.

```
trait Foo { }

struct Bar<'a> {
    handlers: Vec<&'a mut Foo>,
}
```

I have another struct `Stu` which implements `Foo`, and has a method `add` to add itself to `bar`.

```
struct Stu { }

impl Foo for Stu { }

impl Stu {
    fn add(&mut self, bar: &mut Bar) {
        bar.handlers.push(&mut self);
    }
}
```

Because there are many kinds of structs that implement `Foo` and the actions finished in `add` method are varied and I need a struct that holds all of them (which is `Bar` here), I wrote the above code. But the compiler complains:

> the trait bound `&mut Stu: Foo` is not satisfied

How can I fix this or realize my desired end goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the error method more carefully:

> the trait bound `&mut Stu: Foo` is not satisfied

versus:

> ```
> impl Foo for Stu { }
> ```

You have implemented `Foo` for `Stu`, not for `&mut Stu`.

In Rust, a value, immutable reference and mutable reference are three distinct entities, and you can implement a trait for either of them independently.

---

The second corner case is that `&mut self` is not pattern matching. In regular pattern matching, `&mut a: &mut A` means that `a` is of type `A`, and indeed the *other* parameters are so treated.

However, confusingly, `&mut self` is just syntactic sugar for `self: &mut Self`...

So the type of `self` here is `&mut Stu`, and therefore you should not qualify it further in the `push` call.

---

Therefore, you have to correct your code to:

```
impl Stu {
    fn add(&mut self, bar: &mut Bar) {
        bar.handlers.push(self);
    }
}
```

At this point, you will get an error about lifetime constraints: it is not guaranteed here that `self` will outlive `Bar`. You need to annotate it (use the same lifetime) to make it work:

```
impl Stu {
    fn add<'a>(&'a mut self, bar: &mut Bar<'a>) {
        bar.handlers.push(self);
    }
}
```

*Note: when annotating lifetimes, it is unnecessary to annotate them all; it's only necessary to insert a name for those that you want to constrain.*

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your program to include explicit lifetime `<'a, 'b>` which leads to successful compilation.

```
trait Foo { }

struct Bar<'a> {
    pub handlers: Vec<&'a mut Foo>,
}

struct Stu;

impl Foo for Stu { }

impl Stu {
    fn add<'a,'b> (&'a mut self, bar: &'b mut Bar<'a>) {
        bar.handlers.push(self);
    }
}
fn main(){
    println!("{:?}", "success");
}
```